# Signalr as an service api

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Is it possible to use signalr as a api service? Many places i have seen using 
webapi as aservice api. i don't want to use webpi. Angular + signalr with 
persistent connection as Service(api) this is what i want to achieve at the end. I dont want to use hub for connection instead i want to go with low level layer i.e persistent connection. In ProcessRequest i want to process all the logic required for the api connection with sql server etc. I am not sure whether i am in the right direction